# Pandas: Grouping depending on conditional count

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to group a dataframe in Pandas (Python2.7) depending on a progressive count that resets every time a condition is not met anymore. It looks like:

```
date                      condition        count   
01,01,2018 08:00             A               1
01,01,2018 08:01             A               2
01,01,2018 08:03             A               3
01,01,2018 08:04             B               1
01,01,2018 08:07             B               2
01,01,2018 08:10             B               3
01,01,2018 08:13             B               4
01,01,2018 08:14             C               1
01,01,2018 08:16             C               2
01,01,2018 08:18             C               3
01,01,2018 08:20             C               4
01,01,2018 08:21             C               5
01,01,2018 08:22             A               1
01,01,2018 08:24             A               2
01,01,2018 08:25             B               1
01,01,2018 08:27             B               2
01,01,2018 08:29             B               3
01,01,2018 08:30             C               1
```

I am trying to obtain:

```
date                      condition        count   
01,01,2018 08:00             A               3
01,01,2018 08:04             B               4
01,01,2018 08:14             C               5
01,01,2018 08:22             A               2
01,01,2018 08:25             B               3
01,01,2018 08:30             C               1
```

As you can see, it is not possible to group just by A,B,C...because the groups depend on the fact that the condition is changing, rather than the condition itself. That's why I have created the count, that could help in this purpose. I have tried `df2=df.groupby(['condition', 'date']).where(df['count']<df['count'].shift(1)`, `for` cycles...but I get errors of syntax, or definition, or key, or "Cannot access callable attribute 'where' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method", and many others depending on the attempt.

I hope some of you can suggest how to solve this, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create helper `Series` with compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values by `ne` (`!=`) with[`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
g = df['condition'].ne(df['condition'].shift()).cumsum()
d = {'date':'first', 'condition':'first','count':'last'}
df = df.reset_index().groupby(g, as_index=False).agg(d)
print (df)
               date condition  count
0  01,01,2018 08:00         A      3
1  01,01,2018 08:04         B      4
2  01,01,2018 08:14         C      5
3  01,01,2018 08:22         A      2
4  01,01,2018 08:25         B      3
5  01,01,2018 08:30         C      1
```

Comment: One more thing: if now I have to add to the just formed groups other columns that comes from df, for which I have to perform sum, average, etc. how do I add them? Thanks

Comment: @LucaSignoria - then add it to `dict` like `d = {'date':'first', 'condition':'first','count':'last', 'col':'sum', 'another col':'mean'}`